# rails adding "static_content" on routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have routes that work perfectly on one machine, but on another machine they are failing and I've had a hard time to figure out what is wrong. On the failing machine it return the following errors for get /groups/my and groups/ respectively

```
No route matches {:controller=>"groups/owner/static_content", :topic=>"general"}
No route matches {:controller=>"groups/static_content", :topic=>"general"}
```

I have no idea where

> static_controller

and

> :topic=>"general"

come from since they don't appear anywhere in my routes file. Basically I have a route like

```
namespace :groups , :as => nil do
    root :to => 'groups#index'
    resources :groups, :only => [:show, :new, :create], :path => '' do
      collection do
        get :search
        get 'my' => 'owner/groups#my', :as => :my
      end
      member do
        post :subscribe
      end
      ... other resources within a group
     end
    end
```

Any idea what I have done wrong or I'm missing? I'm using rails 3.2.2 and ruby 1.9.3 on rvm

Comment: try running `rake routes`, it might clarify some more of your routing issues. `static_content` and `:topic=>"general"` are being called from the view, you should look there for any clues.

Comment: I did, it shows the paths as I expect them to be. /groups/my(.:format)   and /groups(.:format) both with GET

Comment: And the `:root => "?#?"` ? is it listed in rake routes? Also you might want to take a look at index.html.erb in groups, see if there is some kind of `<%= link_to "Something" general_groups_static_content_path %>` or something.

Comment: You are right it was hidden somewhere in the views .. you can write an answer for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A route is usually called from the views, so always check your view for `action_controller_name_path` if Controller::Action can not be found!